# How to Parse MVC4 API Controller response in android using android-kSOAP2-example

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to android and I am like to parse a web API response (This API created in MVC4 using Web API template). I hosted this service on my server you can have a look on it.

http://railapi.digiwebtech.com/api/values

I did some Google research and found some useful links,from that i got and idea how to parse .Net web service. But I am unable to parse MVC API Controller response.
These are the links which I got from search.

[Parse Dot Net Web service 3.5](http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100&aaid=122)

https://github.com/thira/blog-demos/tree/master/android-kSOAP2-example

This both examples are parsing Dot Net web service built in .Net 3.5 but I am using asp.net MVC4 Web API service which is not a ".asmx" type.

If anyone have any idea about how to parse this or any link. Please reply me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is simple xml data, try any xml parser to parse this web service.

Comment: I try with XmlPullParser, but this shows me error. when i search error on Google then i found that i should use android-kSOAP2.